# How to add marker clusterer into googlemaps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I'm new to this google-maps and javascript, I have go through these [examples](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/docs/examples.html).But I still no idea how to apply it into my codes, It doesn't works.Hope someone can help me.Thank you.

```
  // this variable will collect the html which will eventually be placed in the side_bar
  var side_bar_html = "";

  // arrays to hold copies of the markers and html used by the side_bar
  // because the function closure trick doesnt work there
  var gmarkers = [];


  // A function to create the marker and set up the event window
  function createMarker(point,name,html) {
    var marker = new GMarker(point);
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
      marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
    });
    // save the info we need to use later for the side_bar
    gmarkers.push(marker);
    // add a line to the side_bar html
    side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + (gmarkers.length-1) + ')">' + name + '<\/a><br>';
     return marker;
  }


  // This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window
  function myclick(i) {
    GEvent.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
  }


  // create the map
  var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
  map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
  map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
  map.setCenter(new GLatLng( 43.907787,-79.359741), 8);

  // add the points    
  var point = new GLatLng(43.65654,-79.90138);
  var marker = createMarker(point,"This place","Some stuff to display in the<br>First Info Window")
  map.addOverlay(marker);

  var point = new GLatLng(43.91892,-78.89231);
  var marker = createMarker(point,"That place","Some stuff to display in the<br>Second Info Window")
  map.addOverlay(marker);

  var point = new GLatLng(43.82589,-78.89231);
  var marker = createMarker(point,"The other place","Some stuff to display in the<br>Third Info Window")
  map.addOverlay(marker);


  // put the assembled side_bar_html contents into the side_bar div
  document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;

}
```

The sidebar is made next to the google-maps.Hope someone can take a look on my code.

Comment: I believe you are using a deprecated API `GMap2`. Do you mind putting it into a JsFiddle and I'll have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you got there is pretty good actually.

Let me know to simplify it a bit more. 
So to get clusterer going you'll need the following bits and pieces.

1. Your project will have to import the [markerclusterer.js](http://jsfiddle.net/SamuelToh/bvu6vgxu/1/) file.
2. You need an `array` of markers.
3. You need to instantiate the `MarkerClusterer` object.

That is all, straight forward.

**1: Instantiation of markers**

I can see from the code you have already done it.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: '1111'
    });
```

**2: Building an array of markers**

Nothing much here. Basically you declare an `[]` object and push the markers into it.

```
var markers = [ marker, marker2, marker3 ];
```

**3: Instantiate the `MarkerClusterer` object**

I guess the only challenging part is this one. As mentioned before, you'll new to import the markerclusterer.js file.

Build an object to hold whatever configuration that is needed for the `MarkerClusterer` object and instantiate it.

```
markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
        imagePath: 'https://googlemaps.github.io/js-marker-clusterer/images/m',
        gridSize: 10,
        minimumClusterSize: 2
    });
```

Here is an example;

[Clusterer](http://jsfiddle.net/SamuelToh/bvu6vgxu/1/)